# Advanced number formatting with incrementing suffix- javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I need some help with my function. I am new to coding and this task is part of Coderslang apprentice level tasks.

> Implement a function that If n < 1000, it should be rounded to a single digit after a decimal point Else, to cut down the length of a number, we need to use letters 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T' to represent thousands, millions, billions or trillions. We're not really interested in being super precise here. **If the number exceeds 999.99T it becomes 1.00aa, after 999.99aa goes 1.00ab.
> When the number gets as high as 999.99az it will next turn into 1.00ba and so on.**

The bold text is where I am having an issue, I am not sure how best to write this function and need help. Below is what I have tried so far but I am failing two parts of the test-  *The function formatNumber should work properly for numbers less than 999az. And the function formatNumber should not cut trailing zeros.*

My code so far:

```
export const formatNumber = (n) => {
  let number = n;
  let suffix = [97, 92];
  let newNumber = "";

  if (n < 1000) {
        return n.toFixed(1);
      } else if (n < 1000000) {
          return (n / 1000).toFixed(2) + 'K';
      } else if (n < 1000000000) {
          return (n / 1000000).toFixed(2) + 'M'; 
      } else if (n < 1000000000000) {
          return (n / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + 'B';
      } else if (n < 1000000000000000){
          return (n / 1000000000000).toFixed(2) + 'T';
      } 

  while (number > 1000) {
    (number /= 1000);
    if (suffix[1] < 122) {
      suffix[1]++;
    } else {
      suffix[0]++;
      suffix[1] = 97
    } 
  }

  const stringNumber = String(number);
  const i = stringNumber.indexOf(".");
  
  if (i >= 0) {
    newNumber = stringNumber.substring(0, i) + "." + stringNumber.substring(i + 1, i + 3);
  } else {
    newNumber = stringNumber + ".00";
  }  
     
  return newNumber + String.fromCharCode(suffix[0]) + String.fromCharCode(suffix[1]);
}
```

I have searched this forum and others and am struggling, any help would be appreciated. I feel that either I am over complicating the thought process or I'm missing something obvious. Is it my while loop? I have tried number.toFixed and number.toExponential without luck

Comment: It will become `1.00ba` when you have a 1 followed by **90 zeros**. I wonder if even bigint is capable of representing this.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very simple fix, I was over complicating this.

````
export const formatNumber = (n) => {
  let number = n;
  let suffix = [97, 92];
  let newNumber = "";

  if (n < 1000) {
        return n.toFixed(1);
      } else if (n < 1000000) {
          return (n / 1000).toFixed(2) + 'K';
      } else if (n < 1000000000) {
          return (n / 1000000).toFixed(2) + 'M'; 
      } else if (n < 1000000000000) {
          return (n / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + 'B';
      } else if (n < 1000000000000000){
          return (n / 1000000000000).toFixed(2) + 'T';
      } 

  while (number > 1000) {
    (number /= 1000);
    if (suffix[1] < 122) {
      suffix[1]++;
    } else {
      suffix[0]++;
      suffix[1] = 97
    } 
  }

  newNumber = number.toFixed(2);
     
  return newNumber + String.fromCharCode(suffix[0]) + String.fromCharCode(suffix[1]);
}```
````